# Cannot use ssh to clone git repository with Concourse

Tags: git, ssh, concourse

We are using a Concourse instance deployed to and EC2 instance using docker-compose, as outlined [here](https://concourse.ci/docker-repository.html).

Things are mostly working well. However, we can't seem to clone git resources using SSH. We get this error:

```
resource script '/opt/resource/check []' failed: exit status 128

stderr:
Identity added: /tmp/git-resource-private-key (/tmp/git-resource-private-key)
Cloning into '/tmp/git-resource-repo-cache'...
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

We've used Concourse in the past, so we're reasonably sure that we have the resource configured correctly, but I've attached a sample as well.

```
- name: vision_build
  type: git
  source:
    private_key: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      ***************************
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    uri: git@github.com:someorg/someapp.git
```

Cloning works correctly with username/password authentication, but we'd like to use read only deploy keys.

Another symptom that we are seeing is the inability to hijack our jobs. It's unclear if they are connected, but seems possible given that they both have to do with SSH. Hijack comes back with this message:

```
error: websocket: bad handshake
```

Comment: is your private key's corresponding puiblic key configured on the  github side under `someorg/someapp` ?  Either as a deployment key, or as a user in your org dedicated to that activity?  Sounds to me like you didn't add access for the key in github.

Comment: Thanks Dan, it looks like you might be right. We did configure the corresponding public key to be a deploy key for the repo, but it seems that we made a mistake along the way. A local test using the same private key failed. We'll retry with a confirmed working private key.

Comment: We verified that they key was configured correctly. It turns out that there are network rules that prevent talking to the external internet over SSH. We are going to use https in the short term, and will approach loosening some of the network rules as a longer term approach.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading my comment to an answer.

is your private key's corresponding puiblic key configured on the github side under someorg/someapp ? Either as a deployment key, or as a user in your org dedicated to that activity? Sounds to me like you didn't add access for the key in github.